# Simple batch request for Graph API returning Unsupported Post Request error

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, python-requests, facebook-batch-request

I'm trying to get public engagement metrics via the Graph API for a list of links. Since there are a lot of them, a batch request is necessary to avoid hitting the rate limits. Using the [engagement endpoint for links](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.0/url) and the  [batch API guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/making-multiple-requests/) provided by Facebook, I formatted the batch request as a list of dictionaries and submitted via POST instead of get.

But when I run my code (see below) I get an Unsupported Post Request error.

I'm behind and exhaused and any help would be greately appreciated.

Here's my code:

```
import requests
import json 
from fbauth import fbtoken

link1 ='https://www.nytimes.com/2018/07/02/world/europe/angela-merkel-migration-coalition.html'
link2 ='https://www.nytimes.com/2018/07/02/world/europe/trump-nato.html'

# input dictionary for request
batch=[{"method":"GET", "relative_url": '/v3.0/url/?id={0}'.format(link1)},
   {"method":"GET", "relative_url": '/v3.0/url/?id={0}'.format(link2)}]

url = 'https://graph.facebook.com'
payload = json.dumps(batch)
headers = {'access_token : {0}'.format(fbtoken)}
response = requests.post(url, data=payload)
Robj = response.json()

print(Robj)
```

And here's the error:

```
{'error': {'message': 'Unsupported post request. Please read the Graph 
API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api', 
'type': 'GraphMethodException', 'code': 100, 'error_subcode': 33, 
'fbtrace_id': 'AcxF9FGKcV/'}}
```

Comment: _“Since there are a lot of them, a batch request is necessary to avoid setting the rate limits.”_ - keep dreaming … https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/advanced/rate-limiting#faq: _“You can also use the Batch API to batch your requests, but note that each sub-request is its own API call […]”_ Your above batch would be considered _two_ API calls, so you are not saving anything here in regard to rate limits.

Comment: Saves on HTTP roundtrip though

Comment: Try `requests.post(url, json=batch)`

Comment: I did but it didn't work, sadly. :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the batch requests using the `batch` parameter like so:

`payload = {'batch': json.dumps(batch)}`